# Error: Could not find or load main class ActionChecker при запуске jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

Не могу справиться с генерацией jar.
Исходные данные:
Проект Intellij Idea, сгенерирован через maven.
Непосредственно в папке java находится класс с методом main ActionChecker
Содержание pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>HKFB-actions</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HKFB-actions</name>


    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>ActionChecker</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Содержание manifesf.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.commons.lang3
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: dev@commons.apache.org
Bnd-LastModified: 1394888296110
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache
Main-Class: ActionChecker
Specification-Title: Apache Commons Lang
Bundle-DocURL: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/
Include-Resource: META-INF/LICENSE.txt=LICENSE.txt,META-INF/NOTICE.txt
 =NOTICE.txt
Export-Package: org.apache.commons.lang3;version="3.3.1",org.apache.co
 mmons.lang3.builder;version="3.3.1",org.apache.commons.lang3.concurre
 nt;version="3.3.1",org.apache.commons.lang3.event;version="3.3.1",org
 .apache.commons.lang3.exception;version="3.3.1",org.apache.commons.la
 ng3.math;version="3.3.1",org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable;version="3.
 3.1",org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect;version="3.3.1",org.apache.comm
 ons.lang3.text;version="3.3.1",org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translat
 e;version="3.3.1",org.apache.commons.lang3.time;version="3.3.1",org.a
 pache.commons.lang3.tuple;version="3.3.1"
Bundle-Name: Apache Commons Lang
Implementation-Title: Apache Commons Lang
Bundle-Description: Apache Commons Lang, a package of Java utility cla
 sses for the  classes that are in java.lang's hierarchy, or are consi
 dered to be so  standard as to justify existence in java.lang.
Implementation-Version: 3.3.1
Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213
Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Bundle-Version: 3.3.1
X-Compile-Target-JDK: 1.6
Implementation-Build: tags/LANG_3_3_1_RC1@r1577854; 2014-03-15 13:58:1
 0+0100
X-Compile-Source-JDK: 1.6
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
Specification-Version: 3.3.1
```

Но при запуске через java -jar ***.jar выдает ошибку 
Error: Could not find or load main class ActionChecker

Что я делаю не так? В сгенерированном артефакте этот манифест есть, класс тоже само собой есть, лежит прямо в корне ActionChecker.class, но запускаться артефакт не хочет...

Код метода метода main  перепутать тоже не мог...
Самое смешное, генерирую через мавен - ругается что не подтянулись библиотеки, хотя в pom.xml есть информация по либам. Геренирую через intellij idea - ругается на невозможность найти нужный класс... маразм!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("--Обработчик выгрузки акций банка ХКФБ--");
        try {
            System.out.println("Устанавливается соединение с БД, пожалуйста подождите");
            connection = new JDBCConnection();
            System.out.println("Соединение с БД установлено");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка соединения с БД! Приложение будет закрыто");
            e.printStackTrace();
            close();
            return;
        }
        String command;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Основное меню. Введите команду, чтобы продолжить. Введите Help для помощи");
            try {
                command = ConsoleHelper.readString();
                if (command.toLowerCase().equals("exit")) {
                    close();
                    return;
                } else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("add")) {
                    add();
                } else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("help")) {
                    help();
                } else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("equals")) {
                    equalsActions();
                } else
                    System.out.println("Команда не распознана");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка! Приложение будет закрыто!");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    }
```

Все, разобрался, собрал через

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ActionChecker</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

В итоге подтянулись и зависимости и main

Comment: ActionChecker не в пакете?

Comment: нет, лежит прямо в корне архива jar. и при формировании manifest intellij idea предлагает сама варианты классов, подставляет путь просто как ActionChecker

Comment: приведите часть листинга класса ActionChecker с методом main, в нем точно нет опечатки?

Comment: выложил в пост метод main я могу ошибиться в названии метода который подставляем сама idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно опечатка в имении класса в pom.xml, либо сигнатура метода main не соответствует

```
public class ActionChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("123");
    }
}
```

Результат после билда с Вашей помкой

```
Building jar: ../target/HKFB-actions-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Запуск

```
java -jar HKFB-actions-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Результат

```
123
```

В pom.xml вставлял версии плагинов из своего репозитория:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>ActionChecker</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: собирали через maven или через idea?

Comment: в идеи через встроенный мавен плагин

Comment: при сборке через плагин ругается на:
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: и т.д.

Comment: что в пом мне не хватает для формирования всех используемых библиотек? все библиотеки через dependency подключены